# Create PDF from an Excel file without white margins

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I have an Excel document that I need to save it as PDF but i have an image on the header and the footer that needs to be 100% long in the page. Whenever i try to save it in PDF, excel adds a white margin on the sides of the page.

I have already tried **Page Layout > Margins > 0 all**.

I also tried using PDFCreator, printing the document as a PDF files. The margin is still there.

Comment: A work-around: take a screen-shot of the sheet, trim it in MS Paint, and print the Paint image as a PDF.

Comment: Or print your PDF as a PDF, zoomed appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After thousand of tries, i foud a way:

I set all the margins to 0 (Page Layout > Margins > 0 all) and then i printed with the **native** Windows PDF printer: **"Microsoft Print To PDF"**.

I didn´t even knew windows came with a native pdf printer but that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Microsoft Print To PDF" printer resolves the issue for printed document. However, I wanted to "Save (my document) to PDF" so the text is embedded and could be copied.

Also, the "Print to PDF" command cannot be automated using a Macro (or at least I couldn't figure out how), while the "Save to PDF" command is widely documented and allows to predetermine the path and filename using a cell value.

Like mentioned in the previous comments, all page margins should be set to 0. Also, in the Page Setup > Header/Footer, both "Scale with document" and "Align with page margins" boxes should be checked.

At this point, if you Save to PDF your document, the white bleed lines should still occur in your newly created PDF document.

All you need to do at this point is to print your document using "Microsoft Print To PDF", complete the whole process and your printed/saved document should be OK.

Now, go back using the "Save to PDF" command (either in the menu ribbon or using VBA Macro) and your saved document should be ok.

I'm using Microsoft Office 2013 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and fixed it by going to:

File > Options > Advanced > General (section) > and unticking Scale content for A4.

Should be find as long as you have your page sizes formatted correctly.