# Create PDF from an Excel file without margins in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, pdf, margins, border

This question is kind of [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/1064214/create-pdf-from-an-excel-file-without-white-margins), but that solution doesn't work for Windows 7.

I've set margins to 0, no scaling and put colored shape all over printable area (few columns and rows from A1), for testing purposes (image below).

[image: preview]

Also, columns and last row are resized to to fit just before creating second page. Used bunch of PDF printers and I got the same result. Left margin has around 1 mm of white margin. Same result with every PDF printer that I used, so it must be Excel.

Is there a simpler solution? Excel can be used to automatically generate documents, I don't believe it has limitation regarding publications or magazines.

Comment: You wrote *...so it must be Excel*. Could you try with any other common application, e.g. Word or Paint that using them you are able to achieve zero margin on the same computer? This will prove your Excel claim.

Comment: I have no problem achieving 0 margins page with MS Word.

Comment: OK, I confirm I can reproduce the problem in Excel.

Comment: Have you tried to select the area you want to create on PDF and use the "print to PDF" function?

Comment: Had you tried to save as PDF... instead of print to PDF printer?

Answer (score 1):

It might sound silly, but to fix this issue, assign a sufficiently wide border (bold or wider, depending on scale) on the left edge of the table.

This will apparently cover the white margin :)

(tested both with Adobe PDF Printer and Save as PDF native feature)

(it works well enough with right edge too, but you still need to fine-tune the width of columns to fit the print - and referring to the print area indicator in Excel is useless, you have to print and check until you get a proper result)

Answer (score 0):

See the screenshot here:
[image: See the screenshot here]

After editing the document in MS Excel. save the document and **mark it final** to make it read-only.

Then open and print the document in LibreOffice. LibreOffice will print with 0 margins. You may download a [portable version of LibreOffice from this link](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/portable-versions/) that is opensource and 100% free to use.